# How to get a user-selected file and feed it to a python program in Tkinter

Tags: python, file, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I am currently messing about with Tkinter creating an interface for a project I created.  The program takes in a bunch of file paths as inputs for it to run.  I'm trying to create a tkinter interface where I can upload the 4 files I need or at least somehow get the filepaths and the. feed those to the program.  Here is what I have:

```
import sys
import os
import comparatorclass
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile 



root=Tk()
root.geometry('1000x1000')  


def open_file(): 
    file = askopenfile(mode ='r', filetypes =[('Python Files', '*.py')]) 
    if file is not None: 
        content = file.read() 
        print(content) 

def run_comparator():
    comparatorclass.main()
    

button2 = Button(root, text ='Open', command = lambda:open_file()) 
button2.pack(side = TOP, pady = 10) 

button1 = Button(root,text="hello",command= run_comparator)
button1.pack()




root.mainloop()
```

as you can see, I have two buttons.  The issue I'm having is how to connect my openfile function to my run_comparator function such that the 4 files I need to open are passed on to the run_comparator

Comment: you can try passing a function as a parameter or use send the file paths to run_comparator

Comment: Sorry I don't quite follow...

Comment: You can select only one file using `askopenfile()`.  How do you select 4 files?  BTW, you can use a global list variable to hold the selected files.